# Removed much of model but EAP file still large

Tags: enterprise-architect

In Enterprise Architect 10 I removed much of packages from the model (actually there was some large JAR imported by mistake) but the EAP file is still as large as before removal. Seems like EA stores a sort of history or controls versions. Is there a way of removing those in order to get the EAP file storing only the actual model?

Answer (score 3):

Try accessing the following menu before saving the file:

```
Tools -> Data Management -> Manage .EAP File -> Compact .EAP File
```

In case the file is still big you may check whether elements on the Project Browser are used or not by pressing `Ctrl + U` on each selected element. You can also refer to [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20576083/remove-all-elements-not-found-in-diagram-in-enterprise-architect).

Comment: Compacting the EAP file is the correct answer. EAP files are MS Access databases, and deleted records are just marked for deletion, they aren't physically deleted until you compact the file.

Comment: For Enterprise Architect 13 you can find it under "Configure > Model > Integrity Check > Manage .EAPX/.EAP File > Compact .EAPX/.EAP File"

Answer (score 1):

Export your model as XMI then import to the new project.